# Ler Primeira Linha do Streamreader ou ignorar como dar fix?

Tags: c#

Tenho um ficheiro .csv e tou a por os dados numa datatable , mas o problema que tenho de momento é que o mesmo não passa esses dados devido á primeira linha que lê da segunda coluna ser do tipo integer (e o primeiro valor dessa 2 coluna é ATID (Header)) os restantes dessa coluna são inteiros e não consigo dar fix nisto.
Já tentei fazer uma conversão e continua a não dar.
dr["AtId"] = Convert.ToInt32(lineitems[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owk0H.png));

**Erro:** System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <#assetId#> in AtId Column. Expected type is Int32.'

**Exemplo do ficheiro**

PPID ; ATID

asd ; 1

asd ; 2

asd ; 3

dsa ; 4

erf ; 5

```
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:PATHFILE...."))
        {
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            datatable.Columns.Add("PPId", typeof(string));
            datatable.Columns.Add("AtId", typeof(int));
            string line;


                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                   sr.ReadLine().Skip(1);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line + "\n");
                    string[] lineitems = line.Split(";");
                    DataRow dr = datatable.NewRow();
                    dr["PPId"] = lineitems[0];
                    dr["AtId"] = Convert.ToInt32(lineitems[1]); 
                    datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

        }
```

[image: Erro/Debug]

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução para essa linha, e talvez para outras que possam ter o conteúdo inválido, e verificar a conversão, por exemplo usando [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Se o retorno for `true` porque conseguiu converter, senão você pula a linha:

```
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int num;
            sr.ReadLine().Skip(1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line + "\n");
            if (!Int32.TryParse(lineitems[1], out num))
            {
                 continue; // pula para a próxima linha
            }
            string[] lineitems = line.Split(";");
            DataRow dr = datatable.NewRow();
            dr["PPId"] = lineitems[0];
            dr["AtId"] = num;  // número convertido 
            datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```